# Calling dll in Servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I have a situation. A device connected to PC(client side) via COM. The vendor provide me a dll to exchange data with the device. I would like to create a java web-app to collect data from many devices(connected to backend through PCs). So how can I call dll from a servlet? Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Do you want to call the driver of the client from the server(serlvet)?

Answer (score 2):

The straight-forward solution is using JNI or JNA. You should learn appropriate tutorial from Oracle to learn how to do this.

But probably you can do it easier. If for example this DLL is ActiveX you can create script (VBScript or JScript) and then run it from java using utility named `cscript`. Other possibility if this DLL already knows to run as a stand alone application (or you have separate command line app that runs this DLL and provides you CLI.). In this case I'd recommend you to use it unless you have serious performance constraints. It is much easier to run command line application from java than coding JNI.

Comment: but what happens if the dll lies on server?